# How to create a query using wildcards and projections with hibernate search?

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I am trying to create a queries using wildcards and projections with hibernate search, but I'm failing. The users can use or not wildcard on queries. For example, I want to search all terms starting with **"book"**, I use **"book*"** to search.

The method I've implemented, is below.

```
public List<Employee> filtrar(String term) throws DAOException {
    try {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);

        Query query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("*", term));           

        FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(query, Employee.class);
        fullTextQuery.setProjection("id", "name", "phone", "email");
        Sort sortField = new Sort(new SortField("name_order", SortField.STRING));
        fullTextQuery.setSort(sortField);
        return fullTextQuery.getResultList();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error: " + term, e);
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }
}
```

The String `term` passed, as parameter to method, is used to search on all fields(id, name, phone and email). Nothing is returned. What's wrong in that method?

**EDIT**: My entity

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "vw_employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 244555315052436669L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO)
    private Long id;

    @Fields({
        @Field(name = "name_order", store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO),
        @Field(name = "name", store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    })
    @Column(name = "name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String name;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "phone", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String phone;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "email", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    //Getters and setters ommited
}
```

**Indexing method**:

```
public void index() throws DAOException {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);

        try {
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer(Employee.class).purgeAllOnStart(Boolean.TRUE).optimizeOnFinish(Boolean.TRUE).startAndWait();
            logger.info("Indexing....");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Error", e);
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work.

```
Query query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("*", term));
```

If you want to search across all fields, you'll either need to create a Term for each field you need to search, and combine them (a `DisjunctionMaxQuery` is usually best for that):

```
Query query = new DisjunctionMaxQuery(0);
query.add(new TermQuery(new Term("field1", term)));
query.add(new TermQuery(new Term("field2", term)));
query.add(new TermQuery(new Term("field3", term)));
```

[`MultiFieldQueryParser`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/MultiFieldQueryParser.html) is another good tool for this.

Alternatively, a useful pattern is to add all searchable fields into one unstored catch-all field at index time, and when you want to match against anything in the index, you could just query that field instead of enumerate subqueries on all searchable fields.

Also, it looks like you want to add the wildcard to the query here, but you haven't done so.  `WildcardQuery` won't assume any wildcards that aren't there in the term.

```
Query query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("field", term + "*"));
```

Since you just need a trailing wildcard, though, I would just use [`PrefixQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PrefixQuery.html), which is the standard way of handling a trailing wildcard.

```
Query query = new PrefixQuery(new Term("field", term));
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this solution but did not work. The query object generates this query string: `id:MYTERM* | name:MYTERM* | phone:MYTERM* | email:MYTERM*`. Is that correct? Pipe (|) means OR operator?

Comment: Sort of.  `DisjunctionMaxQuery` uses a `|` as the delimiter between is disjuncts in its `toString` output.  It isn't (nor is it intended to be) valid query syntax.  Not sure why it doesn't work for you though.  Analysis issues would probably be my first guess.  Have you tried just querying against just the one field you expect to find a result in?

Comment: Yes. I tried with just one field, and did not return any results. The index is OK, because when I try to recover all records, it works: `fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(qb.all().createQuery());`.

Comment: Okay, that says to me that you almost certainly have an analysis-related issue.  For one reason or another, the term in your query does not match the one in your index.  Maybe you are using a `StringField` and so indexing a textual field as a single token when you don't intend to.  Maybe you are indexing with a LowercaseFilter, and then searching with unanalyzed terms with uppercase characters.  Something like that.  Without seeing how you are indexing your fields I can't really guess at the exact problem.

Comment: I edited my question. I've added my entity class and the method that is called when I want to index my table. Please, take a look.

Comment: I am still having this problem @femtoRgon. Could you please take a look? I am getting desperate.

Comment: I'm not seeing an analyzer being set in the code provided, so I assume you are using the default, `StandardAnalyzer`, in which case it is split into tokens on whitespace/punctuation (generally, see [UAX-29](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/)), lowercased, and english stopwords are removed.  None of this, on the other hand, is being done to the query text.  Do your queries look like they agree with this?  Are the terms in lowercase, for instance, or do they have punctuation or spaces in them?

Comment: Well, I index basically people names. So, for example, names like "James Hetfield", "John Bush", "Lars Ulrich", "Angus McKinnon Young"... For me it doesn't matter if is indexed lowercased. I can lowercase the term. But, I really need to search for "Jam*" and the results return "James Hetfield". Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, have you searched with lowercase query terms, such as `jam*`?

Comment: Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! It worked. In my bean, I was invoking `.toUpperCase();`. I modified to `.toLowerCase();` and it worked perfectly!